# alternative to multiple .forEach() loops for filter in Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a use case to filter key/value pairs that have a value of zero out of the following dataset.  If all the values are zero for the given key then the key/value pair is to be filtered out entirely (as is the case for keys 41521, 41530).

```js
    const simpleData = {
        "41511": {
            "count": 0,
            "probability": 0.000017
        },
        "41521": {
            "count": 0,
            "probability": 0
        },
        "41530": {
            "count": 0,
            "probability": 0
        },
        "41540": {
            "count": 0,
            "probability": 0.000085
        },
        "41551": {
            "count": 1,
            "probability": 1
        }
    };

    acc = {};

    Object.entries(simpleData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        acc[key] = {};
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (v !== 0) acc[key][k] = v;
        });
        if (Object.keys(acc[key]).length === 0) delete acc[key];
    });

    // console.log('simpleData', simpleData);
    console.log('acc ', acc);
```

The current approach uses two `.forEach()` loops.  Is there a different way to do this filtering that avoids multiple `.forEach()` loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const simpleData = {
    "41511": {
        "count": 0,
        "probability": 0.000017
    },
    "41521": {
        "count": 0,
        "probability": 0
    },
    "41530": {
        "count": 0,
        "probability": 0
    },
    "41540": {
        "count": 0,
        "probability": 0.000085
    },
    "41551": {
        "count": 1,
        "probability": 1
    }
};

acc = {};
Object.entries(simpleData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    tmp = Object.entries(value).filter(([, v]) => v !== 0);
    if (tmp.length !== 0) acc[key] = Object.fromEntries(tmp);
});
console.log('acc ', acc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually multiple loops are not need as you can achieve your goal using the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out the items where the `count` and `probability` keys equal to `0` or in other words to keep the items that have at least one key from `count` and `probability` keys that is not `0`.

Here's a live demo:

```js
const simpleData = {
    "41511": {
      "count": 0,
      "probability": 0.000017
    },
    "41521": {
      "count": 0,
      "probability": 0
    },
    "41530": {
      "count": 0,
      "probability": 0
    },
    "41540": {
      "count": 0,
      "probability": 0.000085
    },
    "41551": {
      "count": 1,
      "probability": 1
    }
  },
  /**
   * filtered array will contain the filtered data.
   * we'll only keep the items where at least one of the keys ("count" or "probability") is not equal to "0"
   */
  filtered = Object.entries(simpleData).filter(([k, v]) => v['count'] > 0 || v['probability'] > 0);

// print the result
console.log(filtered);
```

> The above method prevents you from having multiple loops but now the filtered array no longer contain object but rather each item will be an array where the key `0` is the key from the original object (like `41511` and the key `1` is the actual data (like `{"count": 0, "probability": 0.000017}`.

Comment: This output does not match the output of the original post - there should be no properties with value of 0.  So, `"count": 0` should not be included in the final result (it's in the objects for keys 41511, 41540 in this solution).